# Should I take the entire dataset for Linear Regression Model Training

Tags: python

I am new to the data science and wanted to develop a Linear Regression model to identify important factors to predict a policy holder makes a insurance claim.
There are around 750,000 active policy holders in the books and each policy holder details can extract as a row along with factors.
What I would like to know, should I take entire 750,000 rows of data and split 70% & 30% for training and testing ?
Regards,
Mira

Comment: If you're asking about the 70/30 ratio, it's about right. Other known ratios are 80/20 or 2/3.

Comment: If the size of the data causes memory issue, you can first use a smaller random subset.